# Sending a chunked file with curl and receiving

Tags: php, php-curl, chunked

I have created two file php. The first one for send a file through curl utilizing the chunking method. And a second one for receiving the file.

What I need is to send a chunked file with curl and receive it. However, I am not really sure that the code in this two pages does what I need.

This is the code in the first page (send.php).

```
<?php
    function curlPutThrottle($ch, $fh, $length = false)
{
    if (!$length)
    {
        $length = 4096;
    }

    return fread($fh, $length);
}

    $target_url = "http://localhost/save.php?filename=test2.zip";
    $cFile = fopen ('./test.zip', "r");
    $size = filesize('./test.zip');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    // Let curl know that we are sending an entity body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    // Let curl know that we are using a chunked transfer encoding
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Transfer-Encoding: chunked'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, 'curlPutThrottle');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILE, $cFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, $size);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $result;
?>
```

And this is the code in save.php.

```
<?php
    function file_get_contents_chunked($filename, $chunk_size, $callback) {
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'r');
        if (feof($handle)) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                call_user_func_array($callback, array(fread($handle, $chunk_size)));
            }
            fclose($handle);

            return 1;
        }
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'PUT') {
        $count = 0;
        $file = fopen('./'.$_GET['filename'], 'wb+');
        $res = file_get_contents_chunked('php://input', 8192, function ($chunk) use (&$file) {
            global $count;
            fwrite($file, $chunk);
            $count++;
        });
        if (!$res)
            echo "file not received";
        else
            echo "file received ".$count;
    } else {
        echo 'Not a PUT request!!!';
    }
?>
```

Is this code in these two pages correct for sending a chunked file through curl? Or is it incomplete in some way?

And, if is it incomplete what I need to send a chunked file correctly using curl?

Thanks at all for your help in this.